# How to get the specific serial port on usb-serial hub in Linux

Tags: usb, devices, serial-port

I have a Linux machine with a connected USB hub (5 ports), and I also have a serial hub (8 serial ports) connected to this USB hub. It looks as follows:

Linux -> usb hub -> usb-serial hub -> serial device

If I now run `ls -la /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices`, I see the following output:

```
ttyUSB0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.1/8-3.1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0
ttyUSB1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.1/8-3.1.1:1.0/ttyUSB1
ttyUSB2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.1/8-3.1.1:1.0/ttyUSB2
ttyUSB3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.1/8-3.1.1:1.0/ttyUSB3
ttyUSB4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.2/8-3.1.2:1.0/ttyUSB4
ttyUSB5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.2/8-3.1.2:1.0/ttyUSB5
ttyUSB6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.2/8-3.1.2:1.0/ttyUSB6
ttyUSB7 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.2/8-3.1.2:1.0/ttyUSB7
```

I can "decrypt" this path as follows: in bus number 8, 3rd USB port I connect my USB hub and in first USB port on this hub I connect my serial hub. This is OK.

But how can I identify the specific serial port in this USB serial hub? For example, if I unplug the device from serial port 1 (ttyUSB0) and plug it in again, it will have a ttyUSB8, or next free number, 9,10,11... But how I can get the specific serial port number which my new ttyUSB device is plugged into ?

Comment: Can you not extract the required information with "udevadm info" ?

Comment: no, I do not see any usefull information after giving "udevadm info" command. I have a big output after that command, what kind of information (field e.t.c.) I need to search for ? I was thinking it will be something like: ttyUSB0 is mapped on ttyS3, or something like this.

Comment: Try `udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyXYZ`. No, there's no fixed mapping.

Comment: @dirkt I've tried your command for ttyUSB64 in our prod pc, I've got the following:
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.1/2-1.6.1.3/2-1.6.1.3.1/2-1.6.1.3.1:1.0/ttyUSB64/tty/ttyUSB64

anyway, nothing useful.

Comment: How is it not useful? You said you can decode the path, didn't you? Compare with `lsusb -t`. And no, I don't know why in the question it was on bus 8, and now it's on bus 2 - I don't know enough about your setup.

Comment: usb8 and usb2, it is because, I have two setups. Dev and prod. It is not affect on the question itself.
About path, yes of course, I can decode it. If I will 'cd' in this path: /usb8/8-3/8-3.1/8-3.1.1/8-3.1.1:1.0 inside I will find 4 ttyUSB devices.
I want something like uniq path for each serial port on my serial hub.
My problem is, what after each new device appearing in my system, I want to know the exact serial port it plugged in. So, how how can I programatically access the specific serial port on my usb-serial hub ? Thank you.